# How do I download all features with a particular tag?

Tags: openstreetmap

I'm trying to get all the different features(point, line & polygon) which are tagged with `locality`, from OSM data from a metropolitan sized area

I'm presently working with minimal computer resources so I can't upload all osm data from this region in a PostGIS database.

Is there any online website or service which allows the download of OSM data after filtering it by tags?

Comment: Have you tried the [OSM Overpass API](http://overpass-turbo.eu/)?  What type of features are you trying to download?  For example, roads aren't typically tagged with a locality name.

Comment: @RyanDalton: This was pretty much what I wanted. Can you please post it as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the OSM Overpass API a try at http://overpass-turbo.eu/.

If you don't know the key/value pairs you are looking for or the correct JavaScript syntax, just click the "Wizard" button, type in the feature types you are after.  it will build the correct JS sytax for you.  Then just click the "Run" button to return the highlighted features in your current view extent.

If you want to get a copy of the data in JSON format, just click on the "Data" tab in the upper right and copy/paste the JSON into a text file.

Answer (score 0):

The QGIS Quick OSM plugin implements the Overpass API to download specific subsets of the OSM database.

[This description is in French, but I'm sure you get what it means.](http://www.3liz.com/blog/rldhont/index.php?post/2014/09/26/QGIS-QuickOSM-Plugin-%3A-Obtenir-simplement-des-donn%C3%A9es-OpenStreetMap-dans-QGIS)